# Magento Performance Tuning using New Relic and GD2 seems slow

Tags: magento, newrelic

I'm working on a Magento shop with 10K products and we would like to reduce the loading time to the bare minimum. We use Google Pagespeed and Pingdom Tools for measuring the performance and we have New Relic Pro activated. We are using Magento 1.9.1.0.

When I measure my site using Pingdom, I'm getting the following results:

[image: Waiting time (in yellow) too long]

We want to make it look as follows (and we know it is possible):

[image: Desired result]

What I have done so far is browsing through the website and and watch the transaction traces in New Relic. That looks as follows:

[image: New Relic Trace]

Surprisingly I see that Varien Image components take a lot of time to load. Does anybody have a clue if this is normal? (guess not?) And how this is caused?

Thanks!

SOLUTION: 
It has been solved by installing a FPC (ExtendWare Full-page caching module). Now the store is fast as the speed of light!

Comment: It sounds like Magento stores a cached copy of the resampled images it creates with GD, but you should consider using a reverse proxy CDN for your images (and other static files) as well. For example: set up static.yourdomainname.com to point to a CDN such as CacheFly or EdgeCast and configure the CDN to use your server(s) as the origin and configure Magento base URLs under System -> Configuration -> Web.

Answer (score 0):

This is magento default behaviour. Magento rescales productimages when they are viewed the first time. This includes images which already have the requested size. The resampled images are stored in media/catalog/product/cache and used on the next views. 
So this is a onetime issue on viewing the image the first time.

You could just upload images with the desired size and don't let magento rescale them. Therefore you could rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` to change the default behaviour. Or you could write your own image adpter with a faster library. 
No FPC will solve this intial issue with the image resampling.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved by installing a Full Page Cache (we chose ExtendWare Full-page caching module). Now the store is fast as the speed of light!